Does Oracle field contain all letters from a string?
There is a VARCHAR2 field in an Oracle table. It can contain combinations of letters in any order:

BOWLD
DLBWO
OWB
BW

etc.
Then I have another string as SQL query parameter. It also contains similar letters.
I would like to detect whether the field contains ALL letters from the parameter or not.
Example:
Field   Parameter Result
BLWOD     WB       True
OBLD      BD       True
OBLD      BDW      False

If it were just one letter in the parameter, I could simply use the LIKE clause:
SELECT MyObjID FROM MyTable WHERE ColorField LIKE :ColorParam

But what to do when I have to split the :ColorParam into letters and do multiple evaluations at a single time?

Your table has columns, not fields. Use a recursive cte.

A column in a record is a field, right?

Nope, a column can even consist of several fields. select (1, 'a') b ... returns the one and only column b, consisting of two fields. (And tables have rows, not records.)

Sorry, I am from the Delphi world. And Delphi was created to speak to Oracle.

Old habits die hard.

You can use a correlated sub-query to split the parameter into letters and check that all the letters are in field:
SELECT field,
       parameter,
       CASE
       WHEN 0 < ALL(
                  SELECT INSTR(field, SUBSTR(parameter, LEVEL, 1))
                  FROM   DUAL
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(parameter)
                )
       THEN 'true'
       ELSE 'false'
       END AS result
FROM   table_name 

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Field, Parameter) AS
SELECT 'BLWOD', 'WB'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'OBLD',  'BD'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'OBLD',  'BDW' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



FIELD
PARAMETER
RESULT




BLWOD
WB
true


OBLD
BD
true


OBLD
BDW
false



fiddle

The simplest way is probably using Oracle's TRANSLATE function here that can replace or remove characters from a string.
The idea is to remove all characters that occur in field from parameter. Then we simply check whether there remain characters in parameter, because they had no match in field.
In order to remove characters with TRANSLATE, we want the replace string to be empty. This is one of the very few situations, however, when Oracle's "empty string = NULL" gets in the way and TRANSLATE(param, field, '') would always return NULL. So I just add a dummy character '#'.
CASE WHEN LENGTH(TRANSLATE(param, '#' || field, '#')) > 0 THEN
  'False'
ELSE 
  'True' 
END AS result

Here is a demo:
select
  field,
  param,
  case when length(translate(param, '#' || field, '#')) > 0 then 'False' else 'True' end as result
from
(
  select 'BLWOD' as field, 'WB' as param from dual
  union all
  select 'OBLD' as field, 'BD' as param from dual
  union all
  select 'OBLD' as field, 'BDW' as param from dual
);

Result:



FIELD
PARAM
RESULT




BLWOD
WB
True


OBLD
BD
True


OBLD
BDW
False




Introduction
You can implement a stored function f1 that will have the following input:

input: the varchar you are searching characters inside
chars: the varchar that contains the characters you are searching for
pos: the position you are at when calling the function

Algorithm
You may have your string between pos - length + 1 and pos (where length is the length of chars), or pos - length + 2 and pos + 1, or ... or pos and pos + length - 1
So you loop start from pos - length + 1 up to pos and in each iteration you do the following:

assign chars to tempChars so you can change tempChars without damaging the value of chars so you can reuse it in later iterations
loop index from start to start + length - 1 (of course, if and only if start is greater or equal to 0 and start + length - 1 is smaller or equal than the length of input)
at each step, check whether the character that you have in input at the position of index is inside tempChars. If not, then this is not a match. If yes, then remove this character from tempChars
if you reached the end of the loop and tempChars is emptied, so all characters were found, then the match was found

Outer algorithm
You can implement another stored function f2 that will receive:

input: the varchar you are searching strings inside
chars: the varchar that contains the characters you are searching for

Get the first character of chars and select all occurrences of this character, use a cursor to loop the results and call f1(input, chars, substr(chars, 1) in each iteration. If any of those iterations find a permutation your string, then input matches that. If none of them finds it, then input does not match it.
Usage
Call f2(ColorField, 'BOWLD') where you need it.
